# Is one allowed to wear a head lamp on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, melacha-creative-work, muktzeh, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

On Lail Shabbat (Fri. night) Someone attends a shul that is some distance away from his home. The way home has no street lighting or other form of lighting (e.g. no full moon and few houses).

There is no eruv on his way home, and he has put on the headlamp before Shabbat began. Can he wear this handlamp to light his way home?

**Consideration factors**

- Is the headlamp considered muktzah?
- Is wearing the headlamp similar to wearing jewelry, which is permitted on Shabbat? I.e. is he violating the rule of carrying?
- Other problems / violations not mentioned

Please do not factor the notion that he should stay home and not go to shul, altogether. Assume that he was a guest who went to shul and didn't know how dark it was on the road and there happened to be a lit headlamp available for him to use.

Comment: Without getting too much into it, "a need for him to be in shul" is no excuse to carry on Shabbat, unless the need is to treat a congregant who's having a heart attack.

Comment: If you were to wear a headlamp and it went out during the walk, you would be able to see far less than if you had not worn a headlamp in the first place. It is better to let your eyes adjust to the darkness......then eat carrots when you get home.

Comment: @HaLailahHaZeh This may be true. However, the purpose of the head lamp, here, is more to prevent danger on the side of the road. Drivers need to see you walking on the side of the road.

Comment: @danf for drivers to see you one can wear a reflector strap. That is 100% permitted.

Comment: @GershonGold Yes, but it doesn't light up your way on the road.

Comment: It might help if it was made in a way that the lamp part also functions as decoration for the hat.  You would look really silly wearing it in shul, but maybe something like [this](https://www.chasing-fireflies.com/product/anglerfish-costume-for-kids.do).

Comment: @GershonGold _you one can wear a reflector strap. That is 100% permitted_ - says who? (assuming it's not sewn on to your clothes).

Comment: @DannySchoemann http://www.thelakewoodscoop.com/news/2017/03/wearing-reflectors-on-shabbos.html

Comment: @GershonGold - your statement _you one can wear a reflector strap. That is 100% permitted_ is VERY misleading. You can wear it AS A BELT, AND NO OTHER BELT ON THAT ITEM OF CLOTHING.

Comment: Mishnah Berurah says there's no need to go to shul, even on Yom Kippur, if you live more than eighteen minutes away. Just thought I'd throw that out there, in light of what @DoubleAA said. Bli neder I'll find the exact place.

Comment: @ezra I am aware that no one needs to attend shul. See the last paragraph. Let's say someone was in shul and didn't know how dark it would be to get home, but the headlamp was available. It's clear that one needs to do what he can to be safe, and the headlamp will assist in his safety, if it's permitted. Please forego all the peripheral ideas for this question. We also know that he can stay in shul ... maybe.